# Tradeoffs between large and small indexes on Elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch

Generally speaking, which are the tradeoffs (in terms of performance and memory usage) between large and small indexes in Elasticsearch?

**Elaborating a little:**
Consider a cluster with 8 nodes, each node with 1 shard and 30Gb allocated to the JVM.
Consider also a scenario with 50 million of documents per day (all with the same structure and using doc-values), retained for 90 days. Each day of documents has about 35Gb on disk.

I want to run some queries in these cluster, covering a total of 12 hours of data.
These queries are composed by some nested aggregations: a `date-histogram`, followed by a `cardinality` and a `percentile` aggregation.

Considering the amount of data, which is better: use daily-indexes or only a single index?

PS: I know that is a "vague" question. My question is more theoretical.
I want to understand better what occur during an aggregation and how this relates to the number of indexes.

Comment: This is not an easy discussion. It doesn't matter how many documents there are per day, but how much size on disk of indices you have per day? What's the retention period? How many CPU cores each node has? What kind of queries are you going to run on this data? What is the frequency of these queries? Do you have the possibility of load testing various config scenarios?

Comment: Thanks for the comment @AndreiStefan! My question is more theoretical and the scenario presented in the question isn't real. The reason to my question is that I didn't found any detailed posts explaining how an aggregation works (in low-level terms). Anyway, I edited my question and added more info.

Comment: There is no theory out there that is going to answer all sizing scenarios for any cluster and use-case. There are some rules of thumb, but to properly size a cluster is all about the use case and each scenario needs to be evaluated individually. In real-life, load tests need to be performed with some real data and queries to see if the future production cluster can sustain the load.

Comment: Thanks again @AndreiStefan. But exists any text/post explaining in details what occurs in Elasticsearch when an aggregation is running? I.e, how the different factors (like number of indexes, number of shards, heap size and others) impact in the execution?